# How can I add users to the web application manually?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, authorization, asp.net-mvc-5, roles

I am writing a closed ASP .NET MVC 5.1 application. Only authorized people can get in. I want to delete register action from the application. Can I add users manually by adding new rows in database associated with the web application?

How to do so in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally not easy to add users directly to the database tables, as there are many interrelated concerns such as permissions, roles, and password hashing.

However, it is possible to "seed" the database in code.  The following is an example of a `Seed` function using ASP.NET Identity.

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    //First, access the UserManager
    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);

    //Secondly, Create the user account
    var user = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = "ExampleUser",
        UserProfileInfo = new UserProfileInfo
        {
            FirstName = "Example",
            LastName = "User",
            EmailID = "exampleuser@testdomain.com"
        }
    };

    //Last, add the user to the database
    manager.Create(user, "password123");
}
```

This function will run the next time that `Update-Database` is run in the NuGet Package Manager Console.